# Discard theoretically used but technically unused function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, embedded

Is it somehow possible to discard a function/symbol from an output file (.exe/.elf) even if it could be called?

Let's say, a third party library does something like this:

```
int lib_func_get(int c) {
   if (c < 5) {
       return foo();
   } else {
       return bar()
   }
}
```

And you know for sure, c is never < 5, then I would like to omit/remove foo() from my executable to reduce the binary size.

How can I do this? Maybe with the help of the linker script and discarding *.text.foo*?

GCC's linker has a similar section for this, /DISCARD/, but the linking fails because the function is used:

```
refers [symbol], which is defined in a discarded section
```

The background of my question is reducing the binary size of embedded applications, especially bootloaders, where you cannot recompile a third party library or the library is part of the toolchain (libgcc e.g.) and you don't want to modify and rebuild the whole toolchain.

I know, this is may be a hacky approach but I would like to do this.

Comment: If you're okay with manually listing out the functions to discard, you might as well go and make all the unnecessary functions empty manually or by using a script.

Comment: @Mat it will probably complain about duplicate symbols as defsym creates new symbol.

Comment: It is not the way of doing it. Place functions in their own sections. Unused unes will be discarded. If a third party library is badly written no tricks will help you. You

Comment: When linking to a library, excluding some function works only if it is a single module in the library. And then you can provide your own empty implementation and link this before the library.

Comment: @0___________ Since there is a reference to the uncalled function, the linker needs a resolving implementation. It is not unused, as the OP states, it is just uncalled.

Comment: @thebusybee if it is uncalled the nothing can be done. You never know if this function is not called from another part of the library. Dirty workarounds will not help. Application has to be redesigned or larger micro chosen

Comment: @0___________ You can know, if you read the cross reference after linking, or if you read the symbols table. ;-)

Comment: @viatorus Please provide a [mre] for us to work with. As the question is currently, we cannot help really.

Comment: @thebusybee do you really think that is the way of designing the programs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239433/discussion-between-the-busybee-and-0).

Comment: This may be an artifact of simplifying the example, but if you "know for sure that c is never < 5" you can replace the call to `lib_func_get(whatever)` with a call to `bar()`.

Answer (score 2):

In cases where the issue is local the best approach would be to provide a compiler hint:

```
#define ASSUME(cond) do {      \
    if (!(cond))               \
      __builtin_unreachable(); \
  } while (0)

int lib_func_get(int c) {
   ASSUME(c >= 5);
   if (c < 5) {
       return foo();
   } else {
       return bar()
   }
}
```

This would drop both function definition and surrounding code.

Otherwise you can override the symbol at link time:

```
$ gcc tmp.c -Wl,--defsym=printf=0
$ objdump -d tmp.c | grep printf
113d:   e8 be ee ff ff          callq  0 <printf>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This doesn't scale as I need it. The problem is much deeper in code as a single simple call.

Comment: @Viatorus I've added alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it somehow possible to discard a function/symbol from an output file (.exe/.elf) even if it could be called?

No.

> you know for sure, c is never < 5, then I would like to omit/remove foo() ... How can I do this?

So refactor the code and remove the call to `foo()`.

---

Mark the symbol as weak and replace it with an implementation that calls abort, or if you are really brave, just returns. Similarly, you can use `--wrap`. For example:

```
objcopy --weak-symbols=foo the_lib_with_foo.o the_lib_with_weak_foo.o
echo 'void foo() { return; }' | gcc -xc - -o foo.o 
gcc foo.o the_lib_with_weak_foo.o -o the_exe.out
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit, but there are compilers that have similar features.

e.g. the DIAB compiler had/has a feature (on NXP targets at least), to place each function and global variables in separate ELF sections (from *.c -> *.o). In the linker, there is another option, to remove unused sections.

There's also a drawback though, for very big files, you could run out of ELF sections, since you have a max. of 65536 sections.